# Can I do a sargable first letter match on two tables?

Tags: sql-server

```
select value 
from persons p join persons2 p2 
    on left(p.lastname,1) = left(p2.lastname,1)
```

SQL Server. Is there any way to make this SARGable/run faster? I can't create columns on persons table, but I can create columns on persons2.

Comment: You know that the result of that query is going to be a kind of CROSS JOIN, actually?

Comment: How big are the tables? If they are each say a mere 10K rows, the result will be at least 4 million rows. I wonder what will the use of such query be.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ maybe an initial input into some deduplication process using fuzzy matching?

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: This was just for example. There are more predicates. Martin Smith has the right idea, it's for deduplication.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a view on the tables with a persisted computed column defined as the `LEFT(lastname, 1)` of each table, then compare the computed persisted column values.

Here is a test-bed showing how to do that:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons
(
    PersonID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Persons
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , FirstName nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
    , LastName nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.Persons2
(
    PersonID int NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_Persons2
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
        IDENTITY(1,1)
    , FirstName nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
    , LastName nvarchar(500) NOT NULL
);

GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.PersonsView
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT p1.PersonID
    , p1.FirstName
    , p1.LastName 
    , LastNameInitial = LEFT(p1.LastName, 1)
FROM dbo.Persons p1;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.PersonsView2
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT p2.PersonID
    , p2.FirstName
    , p2.LastName 
    , LastNameInitial = LEFT(p2.LastName, 1)
FROM dbo.Persons p2;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_PersonsView
ON dbo.PersonsView(PersonID);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PersonsView_LastNameInitial
ON dbo.PersonsView(LastNameInitial)
INCLUDE (FirstName, LastName);

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX CX_PersonsView2
ON dbo.PersonsView2(PersonID);
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PersonsView2_LastNameInitial
ON dbo.PersonsView2(LastNameInitial)
INCLUDE (FirstName, LastName);

CREATE STATISTICS ST_PersonsView_001
ON dbo.PersonsView(LastName);

CREATE STATISTICS ST_PersonsView2_001
ON dbo.PersonsView2(LastName);
```

Here, we'll insert some sample data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Persons(FirstName, LastName)
VALUES ('Max', 'Vernon')
    , ('Joe', 'Black');

INSERT INTO dbo.Persons2(FirstName, LastName)
VALUES ('Max', 'Vernon')
    , ('Joe', 'Black');
```

Here's the `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.PersonsView pv1
    INNER JOIN dbo.PersonsView2 pv2 ON pv1.LastNameInitial = pv2.LastNameInitial;
```

And the results:

```
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
| PersonID | FirstName | LastName | LastNameInitial | PersonID | FirstName | LastName | LastNameInitial |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
|        2 | Joe       | Black    | B               |        2 | Joe       | Black    | B               |
|        1 | Max       | Vernon   | V               |        1 | Max       | Vernon   | V               |
+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+----------+-----------+----------+-----------------+
```

The execution plan, with only two rows per table (admittedly not a lot of rows!)

[image]

Answer (score 11):

If the `lastname` column is indexed in at least one of the tables then you could also use `LIKE`

```
SELECT *
FROM   persons p
       INNER JOIN persons2 p2
               ON p2.lastname LIKE LEFT(p.lastname, 1) + '%'
```

[image]

The plan for this can have a seek on the table specified to the left of the like.

i.e. `ON p.lastname LIKE LEFT(p2.lastname, 1) + '%'` would not be able to make use of the index on `persons2`that was used above but *could* seek one on `persons`.

The suggestion in the other answer of indexing a calculated column on both sides is more flexible however. As for a nested loops plan either table can be on the inside and it would also allow a many to many merge join without requiring a sort.

Comment: what about [this approach](http://rextester.com/ZGYF75669)? Feel free to add it in your answer if it has any benefit. Would it be using indexes on both tables - and if so, would it be more efficient?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ It could give a plan like this if the indexes are covering https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSzcT.png. I'm not seeing any advantage over the plan in my answer though. As it will still end up needing to read all the rows in the outer table, just now via 26 seeks rather than one scan.

Answer (score 2):

I happen to have a table with 3,423 rows and 195 distinct values in `Name`. I'll call this table `P` (person) and duplicate it to create `P2` (person2). There is a unique, clustered primary key on an integer ID column. I'm using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (KB3194716) Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro 6.3 with 32GB RAM.

With the base query

```
select
    p.pid
from dbo.p
inner join dbo.p2 
    on LEFT(p.name, 1) = LEFT(p2.name, 1);
```

I get 1.5M rows returned in 3200-3300ms (from statistics io).

[image]

By re-writing thus -

```
select
    p.pid
from dbo.p
where exists
(
    select 1
    from dbo.p2 
    where LEFT(p.name, 1) = LEFT(p2.name, 1)
);
```

elapsed reduces to 50-60ms and the plan is:

[image]

Fewer rows are returned (3,423) because of the matching algorithm. The same plan and row count is achieved by changing the base query to `select distinct`.

By creating indexed, computed column

```
alter table dbo.p2
add Name1 as Left(Name, 1);

create index ix1 on dbo.p2(Name1);
```

The elapsed time drops to 45-50ms.

[image]